# Error while installing mysqlclient on macOS Sierra Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I am trying to install mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/usr/local/opt/lzlib/include -L/usr/local/opt/lzlib/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mariadb/server/lib -lmariadb -lzlib -lpthread -ldl -lm -liconv -lgnutls -lnettle -ltasn1 -lgmp -lhogweed -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lzlib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed the library with brew:

```
brew install lzlib
```

But the error still remains.

Dev tools are installed, too:

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Comment: try pip3 and see if you are getting same error

Comment: `pip3` is for Python 3.x installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lines in mysql_config like following:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l"
```

It should be:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```